# TCPDF Takes too much time for creating PDF, How to show loading effect in this time

Tags: php, jquery, dom, tcpdf

I have an anchor tag, with href to a page, where it will generate a PDF using TCPDF. It takes too much time to generate PDF. Meanwhile the interface page remain as such, it shows a loading icon on top of browser title bar. How can i show a loader on the interface, and this loader need to vanish after the download is completed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's my problem too, still searching a solution

Answer (score -1):

Here is something to get you started.

HTML:

```
<a id="loadPDF" href="#">Get PDF</a>
```

JS:

```
// When link is clicked show loading indicator
$('#loadPDF').on("click", function () {

    // Save element
    var link = $(this);

    // Insert loading indicator after link
    link.after("<span> Loading...</p>");

    // Hide indicator after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){ link.next().hide(); }, 2000);
});
```

You can replace the "loading..." with an animated gif. If you want to get fancier you can lookup some code that will make the loading indicator follow the mouse around. As far as removing the loading indicator after the PDF loads is a little trickier. In the example I made it disappear after 2 seconds.

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/conterno/vepx2tfm/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, infact this won't solve my issue. The time to disappear loading effect is not pre-determinant, it can be any duration between 4 seconds to 160seconds. This is based on the dynamic content size need to be written on PDF.

Comment: Does the PDF open in a new window/tab?

Comment: No, pdf open in the same page.

Comment: @Adam: what do you suggest for a strategy to show a loading page when the PDF is shown in a new tab?